# Referencing hashMap values

Tags: swing, reference, hashmap

I am working on Swing code that has a bunch of radio buttons associated with a hashmap of their hex values.  It will then display (in a display area) the color (in the background) along with some text of the hex value of that color.

I'd like it to do this by referencing the values stored in my hashMap and populating these fields accordingly but don't know quite how to do it.  I could hard-code individual ActionListeners (20 in all) but what's the point of coding if you have to do everything the hard way?

Below is my ActionListener & a couple entries in my hashMap.  Thanks in advance!

```
        //----  Action Listener
    jrbRed.addActionListener(new ActionListener()   {//<---Reference whichever button is selected instead of just 'jrbRed'
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
            jlblMessage.setForeground(Color.decode("#000000"));
            jlblMessage.setText("FF0000");//<---Reference hashmap value
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);//<---Reference hashmap value
        }
    });

    // ...my color map of hex values for referencing...
    hashMap.put("Blue", "#0000FF");
    hashMap.put("Purplish", "#DF01D7");
    hashMap.put("Red", "#FF0000");
            //  ...etc...
```

Comment: Okay, so I altered it a little to reflect some changes you guys suggested.  It's kind of a mix but I was able to get the jlblMessage.setText & .getContentPane to work but am having trouble with the ActionListener.  I can only get it to work by directly pointing it to 'jrbRed' or whichever JRadioButton individually.  I am trying to get it to listen to all JRadioButtons but it gives me an error when I put in JRadioButton, rather than 'jrbRed' or whichever.

Answer (score 0):

What if you're map looked like this?

```
JButton blueButton = new JButton("Blue");
hashMap.put(blueButton, "#0000FF");

MyActionListener listener = new MyActionListener();

for(JButton button : hashMap.keySet()) {
    button.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

Then to get the value depending on the button in your listener:

```
jbliMessage.setText(hashMap.get((JButton)e.getSource());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass your radio buttons to have foreground, background, and text `Color` variables, and reference them in your `ActionListener`:

```
private class ColorSettingListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ColorRadioButton crb = (ColorRadioButton) e.getSource();
        jlblMessage.setForeground(crb.getForegroundColor());
        jlblMessage.setText(crb.getColortext());
        getContentPanel().setBackground(crb.getBackgroundColor());
    }
}
```

If you think this is too obtrusive, you can use `JComponent.getClientProperty(Object)` and `JComponent.setClientProperty(Object, Object)` to do the same thing. Then you don't have to subclass.